# Need to change div position in responsive theme

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

[Sample Code](http://dhanushka.net/ex1/index.htm) (I'm working on a Drupal site on a restricted development server, but this is a link to the static html version of the file)

I have the following css that generates the page in the first image.

```css
#slideshow_block {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 280px;
}

#slideshow_floater {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 55%;
  height: 40%;  
}
```

[image: Full screen view]

If I modify the code as follows, then I get the page in the next image.

```css
.region-slideshow {
  display: none;
}

#slideshow_block {
  position: relative;
}

#slideshow_floater {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;  
}
```

[image: Mobile view needed]

What I want to do is to have the page be like the first image on screen sizes larger than 640px. Then once the screen size goes below 640px hide the slideshow in the background and make the search box full width similar to what is in the second image. 
I have added the two pieces of CSS code to the appropriate sections in the media CSS, but it seems to be only responding the region-slideshow `display:none` part. It doesn't seem to be adjusting the position, top or left properties. This is what I get.

[image: broken screen]

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not provide a working example showing the problem.

Comment: Yes please put your html css bootstrap and jquery libraries in a js fiddle and post here

Comment: Research CSS media queries.

Comment: Your sample code css's are broken. Can you fix this?

Comment: Oops... Sorry about that. It was working for me and I didn't realize it was linking to CSS files behind the firewall that were not accessible from outside. Fixed it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you @import you css into html file so it will be like internal css and in this case the style will override you media query so your style in media query doesn't accepted

you have 2 options first you can add `!important` to `#slideshow_floater` in the media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
  #slideshow_floater {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 1px !important;
    left: 1px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 40% !important;
  }
}
```

or the best for me is to rearrange you css files when you import them . now you import them like this :

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url("files/font-awesome.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/style.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/media.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/ksu.css?o7n8rh");
</style>
```

you just need to make the `media.css` is the last file so its style can't be override

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url("files/font-awesome.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/style.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/ksu.css?o7n8rh");
    @import url("files/media.css?o7n8rh");
</style>
```

Comment: Ahh.. That was it. I just needed to rearrange the order of CSS files. Thank you so much :-)